# SQL Snapshot Isolations Phantom Rows

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, isolation-level

Does Read Committed Snapshot Isolation prevent phantom row issue? Does Snapshot Isolation prevent phantom row issue?

I am seeing different results in researching online:

1. Akira Yamamoto states: [phantom rows are allowed and possible under both isolation levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741016/read-committed-snapshot-vs-snapshot-isolation-level).
2. Redgate: ["As with the Serializable isolation level, the Snapshot level prevents dirty reads, nonrepeatable reads and phantom reads."](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-t-sql-transaction-isolation-levels-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)
3. In [answer from Erland Sommarskog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e0623b02-7914-414d-a141-9d43f5686924/read-committed-snapshot-vs-snapshot-isolation?forum=transactsql), he is stating 'Snapshot Isolation On' prevents phantom rows? (correct me if I am misreading his answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Isolation Levels in the Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189122(v=sql.105)):

```
+------------------+------------+--------------------+---------+
| Isolation level  | Dirty read | Nonrepeatable read | Phantom |
+------------------+------------+--------------------+---------+
| Read uncommitted | Yes        | Yes                | Yes     |
| Read committed   | No         | Yes                | Yes     |
| Repeatable read  | No         | No                 | Yes     |
| RCSI             | No         | Yes                | Yes     |
| Snapshot         | No         | No                 | No      |
| Serializable     | No         | No                 | No      |
+------------------+------------+--------------------+---------+
```

For the sake of this question, read committed snapshot should adhere to the same properties of "read committed" in the chart above.